# To get the particular user's ID

Tags: spservices

I am new to SPServices, I am trying to fetch list items from a list.

I am fetching the Title and a person field(Created By).

When i print the Created By field ,I get the person name say XYZ.

But i want to get his ID i.e DOMAIN\NO.

How can i achieve this?
This is my code:

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "AppreciationList",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Appreciated_x0020_Person'/><FieldRef Name='Author'/></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {


                alert($(this).attr("ows_Appreciated_x0020_Person")+ $(this).attr("ows_Title"));

            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to return account name, email, and name instead of just the name, use:

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>"
```

Refer [SPServices GetListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems) documentation for more details.

Example:

```
 $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Tasks",
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr("ows_AssignedTo"));
            });
        }
    });
```

### About ExpandUserField property

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.expanduserfield%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether to use special
>   rendering for user field values that makes them include the login
>   name, e-mail address, Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) address, and
>   title, when present, which causes a user field to behave as a
>   multilookup field.

### $().SPServices.SPXmlToJson

[$().SPServices.SPXmlToJson function](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPXmlToJson) includes support for converting user properties into JSON, for more details follow [this discussion](http://spservices.codeplex.com/workitem/10071).

Example: how to convert response into JSON for User field:

```
 var result = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").SPXmlToJson({
         mapping: { 
             ows_AssignedTo: { mappedName: "AssignedTo", objectType: "User"}  
         },
         includeAllAttrs: true
 });
 console.log(result[0].AssignedTo.userName);
```

Comment: Let me add: The return data from this expanded User field will include all the data above but it will be parsed as it is returned as a single string. I forget now what the delimeter is.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your comment, the answer has been updated.